# Java TCP Client-Server - stuck in infinite loops in both applications

Tags: java, tcp, client-server

I have a Client and a Server, they should have a communication in both ways. Everything worked well, client sent some information to server, and server did something with that information. Now that I tried to implement server replying to. After I've tried implementing that, both programs are now stuck in an infinite loop, waiting for information from the other side.

Here is my code for the server side:

```
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException, SQLException {

    logger.log(Level.INFO, "args[0]: {0} args[1]: {1} args[2]: {2} args[3] {3}", new Object[]{args[0], args[1], args[2], args[3]});

    pathToExcel = args[0];
    pathToDatabase = args[1];
    numberOfAccounts = Integer.parseInt(args[2]);
    portNumber = Integer.parseInt(args[3]);

    listIE = new ArrayList<>();

    listIE = Loader.getList(numberOfAccounts, pathToExcel);

    DBBroker.createTables(pathToDatabase);
    System.out.println("Check value: " + DBBroker.checkDB());
    if (DBBroker.checkDB() == false) {
        DBBroker.insertData();
        DBBroker.insertDataBalance();
    } else {
        System.out.println("Data has already been inserted into the database");
    }
    startServer();
}

public static void startServer() throws IOException {
    //ServerSocket ss = new ServerSocket(portNumber);
    ServerSocket ss = new ServerSocket(portNumber);
    logger.log(Level.INFO, "Server started on port number: {0}", portNumber);
    try {
        while (true) {
            Socket clientSocket = ss.accept();
            BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(clientSocket.getInputStream()));
            DataOutputStream clientOutput = new DataOutputStream(clientSocket.getOutputStream());
            System.out.println("Client connected ");
            //***************************************************************************
            String answer = input.readLine();
            //***************************************************************************
            System.out.println("prosao readline");

            //logger.info("Client logged in on port " +portNumber);

            String[] niz = answer.split("_");
            //System.out.println("niz: " +Arrays.toString(niz));
            serverPortNumber = Integer.parseInt(niz[0]);
            accountName = niz[1];
            receiverName = niz[2];
            amount = Integer.parseInt(niz[3]);
            //System.out.println("Server port number: " +serverPortNumber + " accountname: " +accountName +" receiver name: " +receiverName + " amount: " +amount);
            parseRequestFromClient();

            System.out.println("Prosao request");
            
            
            clientOutput.writeBytes("Kraj");
            clientSocket.close();

        }
        //ss.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

And here is my code for the client side:

```
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    String messageFromServer = "";
    logger.log(Level.INFO, "args[0]: {0} args[1]: {1} args[2]: {2} args[3] {3}", new Object[]{args[0], args[1], args[2], args[3]});
    Socket socket = new Socket("localhost", Integer.parseInt(args[0]));
    //logger.info("args[0]: " +args[0] +" args[1]: " +args[1] +" args[2]: " +args[2] +" args[3] " +args[3]);
    
    DataOutputStream outputStream = new DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
    BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));


    String dataForServer = args[0]+"_"+args[1]+"_"+args[2]+"_"+args[3]; 
    System.out.println("Data for server: " +dataForServer);
    outputStream.writeBytes(dataForServer);
    System.out.println("prosao dataforserver");

    //***************************************************************************
    String answer = input.readLine();
    //***************************************************************************
    
    System.out.println("prosao readline");
    System.out.println(answer);
    
    socket.close();
}
```

Server side gets stuck at the *ss.accept()* line, while the Client side gets stuck at *input.readLine()*

I didn't add the whole project because a large portion of it is not relevant to the problem and it has a lot of code.

Comment: Sorry, still better to use that `ctrl`+`c` and `ctrl`+`v`. Also, your best bet to get this answered quickly is to get a bounty on it.

Comment: Please provide the code and not a screenshot.

Comment: "*...but I thought it would be more logical to send a picture for this problem*" no, don't post text/code as image/link ([more info](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557)). Use [edit] option to correct your post.

Comment: Sorry!! I added the code now, didnt realise it had autoformat, pretty neat! :D

Comment: Server uses readline() and expects line terminator. Client seems to send without. Same when server replies. But you said that earlier server was processing client data. What changed?

Comment: Before, only the client sent the dataForServer string to the server, server used it to fill some rows in the database.
Then on the client side, I added the input stream (called "input"), and the "String answer = input.readLine();" line in client. 
On the server side I only added the "String answer = input.readLine();" line.
I am not sure if I added something else, since  I've made these changes around 5 hours ago, but I think I only added these 3 lines, and program started having problems. Both the client and the server are stuck at the "String answer = input.readLine();" command.

Comment: Try sending a '\n' with each string

Comment: Holy ****!! It worked! Thank you SO MUCH bro, if you are ever in Serbia please contact me I will buy you a truck filled with beer! <3

Comment: I'm on my way:)

Comment: You are not 'stuck in an infinite loop'. You are *deadlocked.*

Comment: Oh, that's the term I was looking for haha. I knew infinite loop wasn't the correct term, as the program wasn't in any loop, but i didn't know the exact term. Well, today I learned, I guess, thanks!

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your server was blocking on readLine().  It blocks for a line terminator.  The client was only sending a raw string.  The solution is to send a line terminator with each raw string.
The same applies when the server responds to the client.

As Simon has pointed out a printwriter would be a good choice if your message protocol is to pass line terminated strings.

Comment: I'd add he should consider wrapping his DataOutputStream in a [PrintWriter](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/PrintWriter.html) and use that if he intend to mostly use texte; that way he can just use the `println()` method.

Comment: @SimonBerthiaume That would only work if he *only* sends text, in which case the `DataOutputStream` is pointless. If he is sending mixed data he cannot do this.